# Error converting a value of datetime to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to retrieve a `datetime` value by converting it into just `Date` format like `mm/dd/yyyy` using the following query snippet

```
CASE 
   WHEN co.RequestID is not NULL 
       THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateFrom, 101)  
   WHEN nis.[867_key] is not NULL 
       THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), nis.ServicePeriodStart, 101) 
   ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), q2.ServicePeriodStart, 101) 
END as READ_START
```

But for some reason it gave me some other format which is like `yyyymmdd` which is not what I wanted. I even tried replacing `NVARCHAR(12)` with `VARCHAR(10)` and `datetime` but it didn't work as intended. I think I have made the conversion properly and I suppose issue is with using `Convert` in `CASE WHEN` statement

Comment: Try `CAST('08/06/2014' as DateTime2)` instead

Comment: What kind of filed type are DateFrom, ServicePeriodStart and ServicePeriodStart?

Comment: @Parado They are DateTime type

Comment: With the information given the code would give you exactly the result that you expect. You should verify that the data types are what you expect, that the code that you show is actually the code that returns the result, and what the result is. There is some link in that chain that isn't right.

Comment: Please provide an actual example raw value for DateFrom or ServicePeriodStart as it appears to you without passing it through any functions.  Also, please provide the same value in the unwanted "some other format which is like yyyymmdd" that you are getting.  Finally, please state what `SELECT @@LANGUAGE` returns for you.

Comment: exact format before applying any conversion is 12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM and the format of DateFrom as it appears after converting is 20131231  and the language is US_ENGLISH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked Fine

```
    CASE WHEN   
co.RequestID is not NULL                                             
    THEN 
CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(MONTH, DateFrom))
+'/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DAY, DateFrom))
+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YEAR, DateFrom))
    WHEN   
nis.[867_key] is not NULL 
    THEN 
CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(MONTH, nis.ServicePeriodStart))
    +'/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DAY,nis.ServicePeriodStart))
    +'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YEAR, nis.ServicePeriodStart))

    ELSE 
    CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(MONTH, q2.ServicePeriodStart))
    +'/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DAY,q2.ServicePeriodStart))
    +'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YEAR, q2.ServicePeriodStart))
    END as READ_START
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with column.So Column is varchar first of all you need to convert it into Date Time

see example

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(10) = '2014-08-06'

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(20),'2014-08-06',101) 
RESULT 2014-08-06          
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(20),CAST('2014-08-06' as DATETIME),101) 
RESULT 08/06/2014
```

your query

```
  CASE WHEN   co.RequestID is not NULL 
           THEN CONVERT(varchar(20),CAST(DateFrom AS DATETIME),101)  
         WHEN   nis.[867_key] is not NULL 
           THEN CONVERT(varchar(12),CAST(nis.ServicePeriodStart AS DATETIME),101) 
         ELSE CONVERT(varchar(20),CAST(q2.ServicePeriodStart AS DATETIME) ,101) 
    END as READ_START
```

Comment: According to docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx 126 is for ISO8601 format, not mm/dd/yyyy. The op's parameter 101 is for mm/dd/yyyy format, so the problem may not reside there.

Comment: You are right,It was a typo,please find the latest script @AndreaColleoni

Comment: @mohan111.. That didn't give me the date in mm/dd/yyyy but it is still yyyymmdd

Comment: It worked fine in the fiddle and many other places in my application too but not in the context of using CASE. Even the query I posted is working fine in the sqlfiddle.So, the issue is not with converting or casting